# Jenkins - Manual build

Tags: jenkins

In Jenkins, when I'm triggering a manual build it is not picking the last check in. Can Any one help with their thoughts and ideas. Highly appreciated if someone have solution

Comment: What do you mean exactly by *check in* ? Is it doing what you're expecting when it's not manual ?

Comment: checkin means latest code change which is commited to my github

Comment: Then it's check-out. Can you show your configuration of `Source Code Management` ?

Comment: In source code management ..I have selected git and given my repository as "https://github.com/trinadh38/trt_src2.git"

Comment: Add a screenshot with all the parameters please

Comment: how to add a screenshot here